# Kinect Infrared Sensor can't detect black color: How to solve this?

Tags: kinect, 3d-reconstruction, infrared

I want use Kinect Fusion to reconstruct a pair of black leather shoes.[image: color]

But when I save the mesh, I get a mesh like this.[image: Mesh]

It's broken.

I know that black color will block all the light so infrared light doesn't come back to the depth camera.But I need to reconstruct leather shoes. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The way its phrased it sounds like you're expecting color to be processed through IR. Only the color camera will be able to pick up color data so that needs to be added to the data if it's not already.
Otherwise, it would be useful to have some more defined problems, like code or any kind of specificity.

Comment: Sorry I'm late. I don't want the color data. I just use Kinect Fusion to reconstruct this a pair of black leather shoes. I just want a 3D mesh.

Comment: Got it. So there are a couple options. One of them is to build your program so it goes through the mesh and normalizes the mesh data to get a smoother data set. However, the simplest solution should be sanding the shoes. The problem isn't really that they're black so much as they are black and smooth, so roughing up the surface to be less reflective will give a small boost.

Beyond that, fusion is far from perfect so you're program will have to be able to take the mesh and do some extra work with it to get a better reconstruction of the image.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. ^v^